# Should I use threeten instead of joda-time

Tags: java, jodatime, jsr310

I came across https://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html.

1) I am currently migrating Java Calendar to joda-time. I was wondering, should I use threeten instead of joda-time? Is threeten production ready?

2) Can threeten library and joda-time libraries exist together in a same application? As I am using some 3rd parties libraries, which is using joda-time library too.

3) Will joda-time become an abandon project since there is threeten?

Comment: I've found this  post clarifying: http://blog.joda.org/2014/07/threeten-backport-vs-joda-time.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Official reply:

As of January 2011, ThreeTen is still what I'd classify as an Alpha. That means that I am
changing method names, classes appear and disappear etc. That said,
the code that is there is basically sound and tells the right time.

As such, I currently advise projects to use Joda-Time until ThreeTen
enters Beta, which will be this year (2011) at some point.

It is possible to have both Joda-Time and ThreeTen in the same
application. When ThreeTen is stable I intend to add the interfaces
from ThreeTen to Joda-Time providing interoperability. However,
interoperability will never be easy as the classes have the same
names.

Joda-Time will continue to be released for a good period after ThreeTen
is complete. But there will be a push to move to ThreeTen if JSR-310
completes such that it is in Java SE 8.

Update, March 2014,

As of 2014-03-05, JSR-310 was [approved](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) for inclusion in Java JDK 8. For more information, see the [ThreeTen home page](http://www.threeten.org/).

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen for a January 2013 update

Comment: How is it now? Would you consider ThreeTen as production-ready?

Answer (score 5):

This is just a suggestion what I would do.

Since Joda-time is heavily tested by lots of users and they still recommend it, that means it's a good library. JSR-310 -- I haven't seen this before this post of yours. Also, I am not sure how many people are using it -- or if it's completely bug free. May be it solves the Joda-time issues mentioned in the link that you have posted, but what guarantees that it is not having a newer bug.

That said, I will wait for JSR-310 to mature and be popular. And probably use in some of the non-critical projects. And, probably, eventually accept it as the blogger says, *"(JSR-310 is) an API 'inspired by Joda-Time'"* . In the mean time, I will use Joda-time.

Looking around the stuffs regarding it, I found this: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/threeten/index.php?title=ThreeTen

It quotes:

> **The ThreeTen project is still in Alpha so methods may appear and disappear at any point.** (Status - December 2010)

*I WOULD RECOMMEND TO NOT TO USE IT RIGHT AWAY*

Answer (score 0):

The main concern about Joda-Time is doesn't support Um Qura Calendar , it's support Kuwaiti Calendar