# For a Java 7 project, should I use joda or JSR-310?

Tags: java, jodatime

Today, I'm working on a Java 7 project that needs this type of functionality. If I could use and require Java 8, that would be easiest, but I'm not allowed to use Java 8.

Obviously JSR310 is newer and is pretty stable, but it's not a fully supported third party library. AFAIK, I can manually download a jsr310 .jar that will work fine in Java 7, but it's not really supported and versioned. Is that correct? If that is the case, I should use jodatime for now.

Comment: Almost 3 years ago but still relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4622918/should-i-use-threeten-instead-of-joda-time

Answer (score 2):

You can download an unofficial Java 7 [backport](http://www.threeten.org/) with an API similar to JSR-310. If you're not already familiar with Joda-time, the backport may provide a smoother transition to Java 8. If you are already familiar with Joda-time, use it.